# How to design the backend to put requests into a queue?

Tags: php, server, backend

I want to design such a system that users can submit files. After they submit a file I will run some scripts with the files. I want to run these files in order so I want to maintain a queue of requests. How can I do this with php? Is there any open source library for this?

Thanks!

Comment: You only need one table with two columns actually `FILE, QUEUE_ORDER`

Comment: Thanks for your help. How do I run the scripts in order then?

Comment: Add another column `DONE` and query that table.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a database..

1. When user submits a file it adds a link to it's location in the file system to the database.
2. You have a cron running that checks for new submissions and processes them in order, when done it marks it as processed in the database.

Comment: what is cron? Thanks a lot.

Comment: A cron is a scheduled task.

Answer (score -1):

I would use [Redis](http://redis.io/download). Redis is a superfast key-value storage; usually its response time is double digit microseconds. (10 - 99 microseconds)

Redis transactions are atomic (transactions either happen or they don't), and you can have a job constantly running without using cron.

To use Redis with PHP, you can use [Predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis).

Once redis is installed, and Predis is set up to work with your script, upon uploading the file I would do something like this:

```
// 'hostname' and 'port' is the hostname and the port
// where Redis is installed and listening to.  
$client = new Predis\Client('tcp://hostname:port');
// assuming the path to the file is stored in $pathToFile
$client->lpush('queue:files', $pathToFile);
```

then the script that needs to work with the files, just needs to do something like:

```
$client = new Predis\Client('tcp://hostname:port');
// assuming the path to the file is stored in $pathToFile
while(true){
    $pathToFile = $client->rpop('queue:files');
    if(!$pathToFile) {
        // list is empty, so move on. 
        continue;
    }
    // there was something in the list, do whatever you need to do with it.
    // if there's an exception or an error, you can always use break; or exit; to terminate the loop.
}
```

Take in consideration that PHP tends to use a lot of memory, so I would either explicitly collect the garbage (via `gc_enable()` and `gc_collect_cycles()` and `unset()` variables as you go).

Alternatively, you can use software like `supervisord` to make this script run just once, and as soon as it ends, start it up again.

In general, I would stay away from using a database and cron to implement queues. It can lead to serious problems.

Assume, for example, you use a table as a queue.

In the first run, your script pulls a job from the database and start doing its thing.

Then for some reason, your script takes longer to run, and the cron job kicks in again, and now you have 2 scripts working the same file. This could either have no consequences, or could have serious consequences. That depends on what your application is actually doing.

So unless you're working with a very small dataset, and you know for sure that your cronjob will finish before the previous script ran, and there will be no collisions, then you should be fine. Otherwise, stay away from that approach.

Comment: Have a thing about garbage?  While you have over complicated the matter, you have also created an infinite loop.  You may want to replace `continue;` with `break;`.  "Take in consideration that PHP tends to use a lot of memory,"?  Well maybe if you are going to bring unnecessary garbage into the mix.  You think 10-99 mS is "super fast"? "It can lead to serious problems."???  If you write poor code.  I am going to guess that you are the one the down voted @JohnnyFaldo.  Did his -2 points came in around Feb 20 at 17:07?  His answer is better than yours.  This is a horrific answer. See my answer

Comment: @Misunderstood you're answer is worse than Johnny's. JohnnyFaldo's answer is naive, yours is just plain bad. You are recommending to use files, using files is definitely worse than explicitly calling the garbage collector, and worse than using databases. What's going to happen when 2 PHP processes try to open the same file? You would need to create a lock for the file. That will lead to concurrency problems.

Comment: Why would two try and open the file at the same time.  Two can append at the same time.  The OS will arbitrate which gets written first. Operating Systems 101.  When processing the file is renamed. The next write will create an new `queue.txt`.  Bullet Proof and simple.  I have been using this method for 25+ years.  There is nothing wrong with using a database either.  The code must be written correctly.  There are no serious issues associated with using a database as a queue.

Comment: Yes there are serious issues with using a database as a queue under heavy traffic. That's databases 101. Operations on files are not atomic, and if you want them to be atomic, you need to write a lot of *unnecessary* code. Just use the right tool for the job.

Comment: You still have an infinite loop.  Change the `continue;` to `break;`

Answer (score -2):

Third party Library?  Too simple to need an entire Library. You could use Redis (see answer by AlanChavez) if you want to waste time and resources and then have to be concerned about garbage collection, when the real solution is not to bring in garbage into the mix in the first place.

Your queue is a text file.  When a file is uploaded, the name of the file is appended to the queue.

```
$q= fopen('queue.txt','a');
```

The `'a'` mode is important.  It automatically moves the write pointer to the end of the file for append writes.  But the reason it is important is because if the file does not exist, a new one is created.

```
fwrite($q,"$filename\n");
fclose($q);
```

If there are simultaneous append writes to this file the OS with arbitrate the conflict without error. No need for file locking, cooperative multitasking, or transactional processing.

When your script that processes the queue begins to run it renames the live queue to a working queue.

```
if(!file_exists('q.txt')){
  if(!file_exists('queue.txt')){exit;}
  rename('queue.txt','q.txt');
  $q = fopen(`q.txt`,'r');
  while (($filename = fgets($q, 4096)) !== false) {
    process($filename);
  }
  fclose($q);
  unlink('q.txt');
}
else{
  echo 'Houston, we have a problem';
}
```

Now you see why the `'a'` mode was important.  We rename the queue and when the next upload occurs, the queue.txt is automatically created.

If the file is being written to as it is being rename the OS will sort it out without error.  The rename is so fast that the chance of a simultaneous write is astronomically small. And it is a basic OS feature to sort out file system contention.  No need for file locking, cooperative multitasking, or transactional processing.

This is a bullet proof method I have been using for many years.

Replace the Apollo 13 quote with an error recovery routine.  If q.txt exists the previous processing did not complete successfully.

That was too easy.

Because it is so simple and we have plenty of memory because we are so efficient:  Let's have some fun.

Let's see if writing to the queue is faster than  AlanChavez's "super fast" Redis with its only double digit millisecond response.

The time in seconds to add a file name to the queue = 0.000014537 or 14.5µS.  Slightly better than Redis's "super fast" 10-99 mS Response Time by, at minimum, 100,000%.

Comment: -1 This answer is pretty bad. You are suggesting to use files, what is going to happen when a conflict arises? Then you would need to bring locks into the equation for this to work consistently. I would strongly recommend you to read a little bit more about Redis, as it is usually used as a queue. It isn't overkill, it's lightweight, and it's atomic.

Comment: I'm not saying there is anything wrong with Redis. I am just not a big fan of 3rd party  add ons. Nothing is free.  3rd party products may help you avoid a learning curve. But somewhere along the line they will cost you when it does not do what you expect and you are stuck with no solution or a workaround.  I checked Redis out because you recommended it.  What they offer either I do not need or I have already written my own routine.  I have been coding since 1979 and over 15 years of that I averaged 15+ hours a day.  There are not many routines I have not already written.